# Find and change duplicate values in a column with batch

Tags: batch-file

In my opac_one-hit*.log I have 3 columns with numbers which are separated with ; 
I want to find and rename the duplicated numbers in the third column and make the repeated numbers look like number_1... number_2

```
@ECHO OFF 
        SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
        for /r %%# in ("opac_one-hit*.log") do (

        FOR /F "usebackq skip=3 tokens=1,3 delims=;" %%G IN ( "%%~f#" ) DO   ( echo %%H >> liste.txt


        )
    )
```

Sample from opac_one-hit*.log:

```
"F96B1606";"216618711"; "BV499630491";
"F96B1607";"216618878"; "BV499630823";
"F96B1661";"216653304"; "BV49843883X";
"F96B1690";"216796148"; "BV49843883X";
```

Result:
the duplicated number in the third column should look like this `"BV49843883X_1"` If there are two duplicates then `BV49843883X_1` and `BV49843883X_2`

Comment: Please show a sample of your input file(s) and desired result.

Comment: @Magoo sample and result are added

Comment: I am a bit confused.  Do all strings in column three get an `_1` or does it only get an `_1` if there is a duplicate? Please provide a better output example based on your input.  That would clarify it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did *not* specified the desired output. This Batch file is a starting point:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%# in ("opac_one-hit*.log") do (
   for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims=; " %%G in ("%%~f#") do (
      echo "%%~G!N3[%%~G]!"
      set /A "C3[%%~G]+=1"
      set "N3[%%~G]=_!C3[%%~G]!"
   )
)
```

This is the output:

```
"BV499630491"
"BV499630823"
"BV49843883X"
"BV49843883X_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you haven't shown *exactly* what your output should be, so I'll have to leave it to you to complete the task.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting @
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set @ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q49821253.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

REM for /r %%a in ("%filename1%") do (
for %%a in ("%filename1%") do (
 FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,3 delims=;" %%G IN ( "%%~fa" ) DO (
  CALL :bumpcount %%H
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:bumpcount
SET "col3=%~1"
(
IF DEFINED @%col3% (
 SET /a @%col3%+=1
 ECHO  "%col3%_!@%col3%!"
) ELSE (
 echo  %1
 SET /a @%col3%=0
)
)>> "%outfile%"
GOTO :eof
```

Note that I've changed the filenames to suit my system, removed the `skip` from the file-analyser and replaced the `for/r` with a plain vanilla `for` for testing.

The `for /f` to remove variables starting `@` needs to be moved to the line before the `for...%%G...` if you want to restart the numbering at the start of each new file. Don't use `::-comments` within a loop, use `REM`comments instead.

First, clear all `@` variables. then, on each line, pass column3's contents to a subprocedure called `:bumpcount`

`:bumpcount` sets the variable `col3` to the value of column3, removing the enclosing quotes. If the variable `@`+column3 is defined, then we have encountered this value in the past, so increment it and append the new count-of-repeats to the contents of column3; otherwise, just output the value as suplied and set `%`+column3 to `0`, indicating that it's been seen before and starting the count for that particular value's suffix.

Note the `(...)` surrounding the `if defined` statement. This gathers all output to the redirected destination.

Since you didn't explicitly show the desired output, I simply reproduced column3 without the terminal `;` as I assume it appeared from your original code.